# issue in JSON parsing by GSON

Tags: json, performance, gson

I have Issue in JSON Parsing by GSON

my JSONERESPONSE is

```
    {"services":[{"service":{"name":"asd","id":"1"}},
    {"service":{"name":"asdf","id":"2"}},
    {"service":{"name":"asdfg","id":"3"}}]}
```

How to parse this response?

means I have issue in creating class of above response
I have created **service** class but i am confusing in how to create ***services*** class.

```
public class services {

@SerializedName("service")
ArrayList<service> list;

public services(){
    System.out.println("services constructor stuff");
    list= new ArrayList<service>();
}

/**
 * @return the list
 */
public ArrayList<service> getList() {
    return list;
}

/**
 * @param list the list to set
 */
public void setList(ArrayList<service> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

}

```
but getting 0 in getList();
```

Note: I can not change the response, so don't suggest it

Thank you

Comment: @ test: Quote the code for what you've tried so far, that will help people help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we need to create a middle layer class to make it right.
**Services.java**

```
public class Services {
    private ArrayList<ServiceWrapper> services = new ArrayList<ServiceWrapper>();
    public ArrayList<ServiceWrapper> getServices() {
        return services;
    }
    public void setServices(ArrayList<ServiceWrapper> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }
}
```

**ServiceWrapper.java**

```
public class ServiceWrapper {
    private Service service;
    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

**Service.java**

```
public class Service {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The following is testing code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String s = "{\"services\":[{\"service\":{\"name\":\"asd\",\"id\":\"1\"}},{\"service\":{\"name\":\"asdf\",\"id\":\"2\"}},{\"service\":{\"name\":\"asdfg\",\"id\":\"3\"}}]}";
Services services = gson.fromJson(s, Services.class);
for(ServiceWrapper serviceWrapper : services.getServices()){
    System.out.println(serviceWrapper.getService().getId());
    System.out.println(serviceWrapper.getService().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Services.java

```
public class Services {

    private List<Service> services;

    public List<Service> getServiceList() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServiceList(List<Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }
}
```

Service.java

```
public class Service {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

your json parsing logic goes here:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String s = "{\"services\":[{\"service\":{\"name\":\"asd\",\"id\":\"1\"}},{\"service\":{\"name\":\"asdf\",\"id\":\"2\"}},{\"service\":{\"name\":\"asdfg\",\"id\":\"3\"}}]}";
Services services = gson.fromJson(s, Services.class);
```

Basically, the json string is not a simple json array format, it is actually a json array inside a json object. So it implies that you need two Class, one represents each item inside json array - Service.java and another plays as a wrapper holding a list of items.

Comment: @spiritwlker Have you checked size of getServiceList() ?

Comment: it prints 3 for me. what version of GSON you are using?

Comment: you are right, thank you, one more question is can we use ArrayList in place of List

Comment: plz can u try it to get value because it is giving me null in all

Comment: @test, Yes you are right, it fails to retrieve the value in service. I've post the new solution in another answer box. it is fully tested and print values as expected.